# bind textbox with core framework

Tags: core-data, data-binding, binding, textbox

i already searched for an answer but without finding one to my specific problem.

i am using core data to save profiles and display them in a table. since core data is already set up, i wanted to use it also for storing application settings.

i've set up the model, set up an array controller to retrive the data, but now, i have no clue on how to connect this array controller to a single textbox.

i try to explain: theoretically my model could have more entries, just like the profile model has. but it has just one with some settings, as if a database would have only a single data row. is there a way i can specify that i want the data contained in the very first row? dont know if my question is clear, its not so easy to explain. please if it was not clear let me knwo and i will try to explain it again.

thanks

igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put application settings in Core Data. Any time you find yourself thinking that you want just one instance (row) for an entity, you're doing it wrong.

Cocoa Touch provides a class called `NSUserDefaults` specifically for the purpose of saving app settings. Look into that, it's almost certainly what you want.

Comment: thank you!just one quick question: does it remember the saved settings on application updates?

Comment: Yes, just like any other app data.